# pdf-lib: Text Annotation generates error "Expected a string object" when interacting

Tags: node.js, pdf, annotations, pdf-lib.js

I am using [pdf-lib](https://pdf-lib.js.org/) to draw some text on top of an existing PDF page. If the text is too long to fit in the area designated, I want to add the entire text to a Sticky Note Annotation, so the viewer can read it if desired.

I referenced [this issue](https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib/issues/161) regarding adding annotations with pdf-lib, and referenced the [2008 PDF  Spec](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/pdfstandards/PDF32000_2008.pdf), Section 12.5.6.4 for Text Annotation properties.

Apparently I'm missing something because when the mouse moves over the annotation icon, the following error message pops up in a message box: "Expected a string object".
[image: List item]

My code is as follows to create the annotation in nodejs 18.9.0 on Windows, with pdf-lib 1.17.1 (latest). (Assumes the existing PDF is already loaded into a PDFDocument object "pdfDoc".)

```
function addNote(props)
    // Add a PDF Annotation "sticky note" to a page
    /*  @param  text    Text of note
        @param  x       X position  of note icon 
        @param  y       Y position  of note icon 
        @param  width   Width  of note icon
        @param  height  Height  of note icon
    */
    {
        

        // Add a PDF Annotation object:
        const annotation = pdfDoc.context.obj({
            Type: 'Annot',
            Subtype: 'Text',
            Open: false,    // Is the annotation open by default?
            Name: 'Note',   // Determines the icon to place in the document.
            Rect: [ props.x, props.y, props.x + props.width, props.y + props.height ],  // The position of the annotation

            Contents: props.text    // The annotation text
        });

        const annotationRef = pdfDoc.context.register(annotation);  // Register the annotation in the document.
        console.log("Annotation added:", annotationRef);
        // Find the Annots dictionary on the current page and add the new annotation to it.
        const annots = page.node.lookup(PDFName.of('Annots'), PDFArray);
        annots.push(annotationRef);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. The solution is that the annotation text ("Contents") must be converted to a PDFString object. Hope this helps someone else.

```
const annotation = pdfDoc.context.obj({
            Type: 'Annot',
            Subtype: 'Text',
            Open: false,    // Is the annotation open by default?
            Name: 'Note',   // Determines the icon to place in the document.
            Rect: [ props.x, props.y, props.x + props.width, props.y + props.height ],  // The position of the annotation

            Contents: PDFString.of(props.text)    // The annotation text
        });
```